# module ‘torchtext.data‘ has no attribute ‘LabelField‘

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to import data like this:

`from torchtext import data`

When I am trying to use data.LabelField like this:

`LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.float)`

It is showing this error:

`module ‘torchtext.data‘ has no attribute ‘LabelField‘`

I am currently using torchtext version 0.13.1

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to some older version like 0.8.1

```
pip uninstall torchtext
```

Then:

```
pip install torchtext==0.8.1
```

This will also downgrade pytorch version if it doesn’t have any dependency.